# Why can't my Pine Script be Published on Tradingview ? Warning: Exit/Exit Fills arguments are not added

Tags: pine-script

How can i convert this to version 5 i am new to Pine Script. I tried to convert it using the editor in tradingview which did not seem to work. And i have a Warning at line 21 shadowing built in variable 'low' don't now what that means either

```
//@version=5

// This trading bot buys at the lowest possible point and takes a 3% profit. It also includes a trailing stop-loss function
// that trails the market price by 1% of the purchase price. It also displays the current market price in a label on the chart.

// The strategy will be executed on a 1-hour chart

strategy('Trading Bot', overlay=true)

// define the ticker symbol for Bitcoin
symbol = 'BTC/USDT'

// get the market data for Bitcoin
btc_data = close

// get the current bid and ask prices
bid = request.security(symbol, 'D', close)
ask = request.security(symbol, 'W', close)

// get the lowest price in the last 10 candles
low = ta.lowest(btc_data, 30)

// calculate the profit threshold (in this case, 3% of the purchase price)
profit_threshold = 0.5 * low

// buy 1 BTC at the lowest possible price
strategy.entry('Long', strategy.long, limit=low)

// set a take-profit order at the profit threshold
strategy.exit('TP Long', profit=profit_threshold)

// set a trailing stop-loss order at 1% of the purchase price below the market price
strategy.exit('SL Long', stop=low * 0.01)

// get the current market price for Bitcoin
market_price = request.security(symbol, 'P', close)

// display the market price in a label on
```

Searched for some explanations but i couldn't fix it on my own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is already in the version 5, it is written in the first line.
You have an alert on the variable 'low' because this is a built in variable 
Simply change the name of the variable to another name as my_low.